# My PC is caching DNS even after flushing it

Tags: dns

I’m learning DNS so I made this test, with the intention of disabling my DNS completely.

- I first set my Ethernet adapter to a random IP in the DNS section (this wasn’t certainly a DNS IP address).
- I flushed the DNS cache with ipconfig /flushdns
- I checked the DNS cache was empty with ipconfig /displaydns
- I rebooted my desktop
- I don’t have WIFI
  [image]

Then I opened Google Chrome and entered amazon.com and a couple more FQDNs
It showed the websites just fine….

I thought it may be my Virgin Router Hub 3.0 VMGD505 caching DNS, so I went into it but couldn’t see any DNS section, so I guess my router isn’t caching.

I also checked the hosts file was empty.

Where is my DNS being cached?

I'm using Windows 10 21H1

Comment: You' may have effectively disable your **IPv4** DNS resolution, but have you also disabled **IPv6** resolution?

Comment: doesn't the ipconfig /flushdns flush the iPv6 cache too?

Comment: Yes, but look at your screenshot -- only **IPv4** is shown. Dis you also disable IPv6 lookup??

Comment: IPv6 is unticked in the adapter settings.  Sorry for the late response.